# Stop .htaccess redirecting everything to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have setup my .htaccess to redirect requests from http ://subdomain.domain.com.tld, http ://www.subdomain.domain.com.tld and http ://domain.com.tld/folder (folder that contains contents  of subdomain) to https ://subdomain.domain.com.tld so my single domain SSL certificate setup for subdomain.domain.com.tld is used at all times.

My problem is http ://domain.com.tld also redirects to https ://subdomain.domain.com.tld. How do I stop this?

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.domain\.com.tld
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://subdomain.domain.com.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^folder$ "https\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.com\.tld\/" [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules should replace everything after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com.tld$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/?(.*)$ https://subdomain.domain.com.tld$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first set of rules matches http://subdomain.domain.com.tld and http://www.subdomain.domain.com.tld

The second set matches http://domain.com.tld/folder, but does not match http://domain.com.tld without the "folder" part.

Edit: Corrected typo as noted in comments and escaped dots in RewriteConds.

Comment: Ok, domain.com.tld stays put which is great, but subdomain.domain.com.tld just goes to subdomain.domain.com/tld, fixed this by changing
    .com/tld
to
    \.com.tld
but get redirection errors from browser.
Note: I've edited my .htaccess by replacing the code under     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

Comment: Sorry about the `/tld` instead of `.tld`, that was a typo on my part. I also added backslashes where appropriate in the RewriteConds - this wouldn't have been an issue in this case, but is more technically correct (note that they are not needed in the domain in the RewriteRule since it isn't performing a match). The rules were intended to replace all of your original rules. I'm not sure what the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .` was meant to do originally ... it would have only matched the condition where the host name was a single character, which is never the case, so definitely remove that.

Comment: No worries, thanks for editing. Although I get "too redirects occurred  trying to open https ://subdomain.domain.com.tld/" and the redirection from domain.com.tld/folder to subdomain.com.tld doesn't work. Triple checked, and on multiple browsers.

Comment: OK, is your https being served from the same VirtualHost? I usually split my port 80 and 443 hosts separate to keep the rules distinct. If they are in the same host, you'll need to add a `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` in front of each of the two rulesets so that the rules don't apply again once it is rewritten to the https domain.

Comment: I don't know definitively (as I don't even know what a VirtualHost is :) ! ), although I assume it must be as adding those lines did the trick for the https redirects! Although domain.com.tld/folder to subdomain.com.tld still isn't redirecting. I'm not sure if I made it clear but domain.com.tld/folder contains the contents of subdomain.com.tld, with your code the folder is accessible (so no looping errors), it just doesn't redirect.

Comment: Does not splitting the ports cause any security issues?

Comment: It doesn't cause security issues by itself, it's just easier to plan your security and keep your rules simpler if they are on separate hosts. If they're on the same host, you have to do the `%{HTTPS}` checks a lot more, whereas if you have a separate https VirtualHost, you know only https traffic comes through on it and you know no https traffic comes through your port 80 host.

Comment: I guess it would also be faster, noticed with the extra checks it's a little sluggish on the redirects. Need to research how to do that. Thank you for your assistance David. Just need to figure out how to get that folder to redirect like with the old code.